# How Can I Create a Bulleted List With Correct Formatting in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a big wall of static disclosure text in my Android app that has various formatting applied through it--it's been straightforward to use `buildAnnotatedString` to get bold, underline, and italics set up. I can't seem to find a way to get bulleted lists to perform correctly, though. I've seen a couple answers on SO where the bullet character (`\u2022`) is prepended to the text, but that doesn't format the indentation correctly on line wraps. I've also tried using `SpannableString` and `BulletSpan`, but I haven't been able to put those together in a way that plays well with Jetpack Compose's `Text()`.

This seems like it should be straightforward--am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same thing and found two options that work. Add a ParagraphStyle to the text e.g...

```
@Composable
fun BulletList(listItems: List<String>) {
    val paragraphStyle = ParagraphStyle(textIndent = TextIndent(restLine = 22.sp))
    Text(
        buildAnnotatedString {
            listItems.forEach {
                withStyle(style = paragraphStyle) {
                    append("\u2022")
                    append("\t\t")
                    append(it)
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Or add two Text fields in a Row...

```
@Composable
fun AnotherBulletList(listItems: List<String>) {
    listItems.forEach {
        Row {
            Text(text = "\u2022 \t\t")
            Text(text = it)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!